# getsockname() doesn't return correct address when client and server are on separate machines

Tags: sockets, posix

I have the following client and server:

Client:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset( &servaddr, 0, sizeof( servaddr ) );
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons( 2000 );
    inet_pton( AF_INET, argv[1], &(servaddr.sin_addr) );
    sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if( connect( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof( servaddr ) ) == -1 ){
            perror( "Client connection error: " );
            exit( errno );
    }
    struct sockaddr_in addr[2];
    recv( sockfd, addr, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) * 2, 0 );
    char addr_str_cli[16];
    char addr_str_srv[16];
    memset( addr_str_cli, 0, 16 );
    memset( addr_str_srv, 0, 16 );
    inet_ntop( AF_INET, &(addr[0].sin_addr), addr_str_cli, 16 );
    inet_ntop( AF_INET, &(addr[1].sin_addr), addr_str_srv, 16 );
    printf( "Client: %s\nServer:%s\n", addr_str_cli, addr_str_srv );
    close( sockfd );
    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset( &servaddr, 0, sizeof( servaddr ) );
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons( 2000 );
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
    sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    bind( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof( servaddr ) );
    listen( sockfd, 5 );
    if( (connfd = accept( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) 0, 0 )) == -1 ){
            perror( "Can't open server socket: " );
            exit( errno );
    }
    struct sockaddr_in addr[2];
    socklen_t len;
    memset( addr, 0, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) * 2 );
    getpeername( connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &(addr[0]), &len );
    getsockname( connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &(addr[1]), &len );
    send( connfd, addr, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) * 2, 0 );
    close( connfd );
    close( sockfd );
    return 0;
}
```

The section of code in question is the following:

```c
struct sockaddr_in addr[2];
socklen_t len;
memset( addr, 0, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) * 2 );
getpeername( connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &(addr[0]), &len );
getsockname( connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &(addr[1]), &len );
send( connfd, addr, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) * 2, 0 );
```

This is a server that sends a client information about the IP addresses of the client and server.  When the client and server are running on the same machine, I get the correct value for the server's IP address, but when I try running the client and server on two separate computers connected by an Ethernet cable, I get zero.  Also, I get zero for the client's IP address no matter what I do (I can't tell if this is correct or also an error).  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: First, the client can retrieve these information using getpeername and getsockname on the client side too (although switched) so there is no actual need to send these from the server to the client. Also please provide a [minimal but complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example so that others can reproduce your problem. Currently it is unknown how you connect and how you receive the data. It is not even clear from your example code if the problem is the contents of `addr` on the server side or if the problem is what gets received by the client.

Comment: Sending network addresses over the network may work in sterile conditions but in general it is unreliable (because of NAT, transparent proxies and probably other factors). Regardless of whether you are able to fix this error, it is advisable to find a solution that involves no such address transfer.

Comment: I changed the question so it includes the entire code.  I just figured only including the section where I think the error occurred would make it less tedious to read.  Anyway this is just a practice program, and I realize the functionality that it implements is rather trivial.  I'm just trying to get the basics of Sockets programming working as I learn the API.

Comment: `socklen_t len;` you must initialise it to `sizeof sockaddr_in`. Read `man getsockname` carefully.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry haven't seen your comment when posted.

Comment: The general problem with "*only including the section where I think the error occurred*" is that you don't know what the error is (otherwise you wouldn't be asking here), so can't know for sure where it is (or indeed that there is only a single error). The point of providing "complete" (i.e. runnable) code is to make sure it actually contains the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man getpeername` clearly states that (emphasis mine)

> The `address_len` parameter **should be initialized to indicate the amount of space** pointed to by address.  On return it contains the actual size of the address returned (in bytes).
>
> The address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small.

That is,

```
    socklen_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

should fix the problem.

Comment: VG. A bit of error-checking on the OP's part would have revealed this.